# postgres- query and count status during specific period of time

Tags: postgresql

i'm trying to query and count status during specific period of time , 
lets say i want to query and count status only for the last 12 hrs from NOW

```
select count(*) as result
from table_events_log
where status ='COLD' AND event_timestamp > (NOW(),INTERVAL 12 HOUR) ;
```

I keep getting syntax error ,  any tips what i'm missing here

Comment: `INTERVAL '12' HOUR` instead of `INTERVAL 12 HOUR`

Comment: `"I keep getting syntax error , any tips what i'm missing here"`: Yes, you are missing the error message you should have told us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not far off.  You need to only *subtract* an interval of 12 hours from the current time, i.e.:

```
WHERE event_timestamp > (NOW() - INTERVAL '12 hours')
```

The full query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS result
FROM table_events_log
WHERE status = 'COLD' AND event_timestamp > (NOW() - INTERVAL '12 hours')
```